# Why am I not able to step through my code in R?

Tags: r

I'm just trying to step through my R scripts for debugging and I noticed that I wasn't able to go line-by-line through code. I have an attached pic of my screen.

This shouldn't be happening. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not certain if you are trying to operate within the debugger (`browser()`), or as @kristang has answered, incrementally executing each line of the code pane. Please explain what you are expecting with your actions and what is instead happening.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484448-Editing-and-Executing-Code

> To execute the line of source code where the cursor currently resides you press the Ctrl+Enter key (or use the Run toolbar button):

Comment: When I clicked the 'Debug' botton to see the drop-down options, the 'Execute Next Line' option was greyed out.

Sorry for some reason when I used the print screen command to copy the screen, the dropdown bar vanished.